# Division Operation with 64-bits on 32-bits Embedded System

Tags: c, math, embedded

I got a problem with an arithmetical operation in C Language: "The Division".
The problem is not so simple, because the embedded system supports not more than 32-bits operations. So, I cannot apply any arithmetical operations with 64-bits (And that is what I need).
To solve this issue, I am using Union/Struct:

```
typedef union {
    long long n64;
    struct {
        unsigned int low;
        unsigned int high;
    } n32;
} My64;
```

I have implemented this in C++ and adjusted to C Language:

```
long long div_s64s64_s64(long long A, long long B)
{
    My64 myA, myB, myBn, myQ, myR;
    int i;
    unsigned char negative = 0;

    myA.n64 = A;
    myB.n64 = B;

    if (myB.n32.high == 0 && myB.n32.low == 0)
    {
        return 0xffffffffffffffff;
    }

    if (myA.n32.high & (1 << 31))
    {
        negative = 1;
        //2 complement
        myA.n32.low = ~myA.n32.low;
        myA.n32.high = ~myA.n32.high;
        myA.n64 = add(myA.n64, 1);
    }

    if (myB.n32.high & (1 << 31))
    {
        negative = !negative;
        //2 complement
        myB.n32.low = ~myB.n32.low;
        myB.n32.high = ~myB.n32.high;
        myB.n64 = add(myB.n64, 1);
    }

    //Bn = -B (2 complement)
    myBn.n32.low = ~myB.n32.low;
    myBn.n32.high = ~myB.n32.high;
    myBn.n64 = add(myBn.n64, 1);

    //Quocient
    myQ.n64 = 0;
    //Rest
    myR.n64 = 0;

    for (i = 63; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //R = R << 1
        myR.n32.high = (myR.n32.high << 1) | ((myR.n32.low >> 31) & 1);
        myR.n32.low = myR.n32.low << 1;
        //R(0) := N(i), bit 0 of R becomes bit i of N
        myR.n32.low = myR.n32.low | ((i >= 32 ? myA.n32.high >> (i - 32) : myA.n32.low >> i) & 1);
        //if R ≥ D then
        if (myR.n32.high > myB.n32.high || (myR.n32.high == myB.n32.high && myR.n32.low > myB.n32.low) || (myR.n32.high == myB.n32.high && myR.n32.low == myB.n32.low))
        {
            //R := R − D
            myR.n64 = add(myR.n64, myBn.n64);
            //Q(i) := 1, bit i of Q becomes 1
            if (i >= 32)
            {
                myQ.n32.high = myQ.n32.high | (1 << (i - 32));
            }
            else
            {
                myQ.n32.low = myQ.n32.low | (1 << i);
            }
        }
    }

    if (negative)
    {
        //2 complement
        myQ.n32.low = ~myQ.n32.low;
        myQ.n32.high = ~myQ.n32.high;
        myQ.n64 = add(myQ.n64, 1);
    }

    return myQ.n64;
}
```

If **B = 0** the function returns 2^64-1. No problem! Else, returns 1 and sometimes -1. Wrong!

Expected: **100 / 2 = 50**
Actual: **100 / 2 = 1**

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Best regards,

Comment: This does not smell right. If your compiler supports the `long long` data type (as it evidently does), then it already supports all arithmetic operations on them. The code generated will not be a single machine instruction, but it will be a lot more efficient than *your* implementation. It is not clear why you cannot use the compiler generated operations.  If it truly does not support 64-bit operations then it has no business having a `long long` type.

Comment: Better to use `1u << 31` than `1 << 31` which is UB

Comment: Could the problem exist in unposted `add()`?

Comment: Simplification `if (myR.n32.high > myB.n32.high || (myR.n32.high == myB.n32.high && myR.n32.low > myB.n32.low) || (myR.n32.high == myB.n32.high && myR.n32.low == myB.n32.low))` ==> `if (myR.n32.high > myB.n32.high || (myR.n32.high == myB.n32.high && myR.n32.low >= myB.n32.low))`

Comment: Your problem is in `add()`  or `1 << 31`.

Comment: Is `add()` is coded to behave well as if is was `long long add(unsigned long long, unsigned long long)`?  Might as well post `add()`.

Comment: Minor: rather than `return 0xffffffffffffffff;`, just `return -1;` to match return type

Comment: Why don't you leave this to the compiler? Any correct C implementation has to support `long long` division as @Clifford pointed out. Did you link the run-time or compiler lib (e.g libgcc)?

Comment: Gentleman, I found the mistake. It is not in this C++ code, but in C code I did not post (I cannot). I am following a very complex/boring guideline. Regarding the mistake, was something like variable names. 
That one is correct! I am sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: @chux I noticed it when I looked to your suggestion. Danke schön!

Comment: @RichardHalbritter You can post your own answer and accept it.  That lets all know of this post's conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Surely your compiler has a run time library implementation for 64 bit divides.  Surely.   Just do the math using standard C (`uint64_t/int64_t/long long`, etc.) and the compiler will fill in the rest with calls to library functions they provide.

It will be correct, and (probably) more efficient than anything you can write.

Unless you're asking this because it's a homework.   If that's the case, go look at your text books and don't ask us.

Comment: Would be nice, but I cannot apply this method. Not a homework too.
As I said, I am not able to do any arithmetical operations using 64-bits and cannot use any C standard libraries.

Thank you anyhow!

Comment: @RichardHalbritter what tools are you using; what processor are you targetting?

Comment: You don't need library support for arithmetic operations on built-in types.

Comment: @Clifford On the cortex-m3, we link in a bunch of vendor supplied library functions for 64 bit math:   `__aeabi_uidiv, __aeabi_idiv, __aeabi_uidivmod, __aeabi_uldivmod, etc.` It's not libc, but it's vendor supplied intrinsic functions to supply math functions for processors that don't support it natively.

Comment: @RussSchultz : It is perhaps compiler dependent;  I am using ARM's compiler and these functions are tightly coupled to the compiler (i.e. included with it and linked automatically - I am not sure there is any means to prevent linking them).  Still is is an unusual requirement to have compiler support for `long long` but not to use the built-in operations/intrinsics.

Comment: @clifford  I think we're saying the same thing.  Just write`uint64_t a = 999ULL/13ULL` in your C function and the tool chain will provide either the correct instructions or a call to a function to make it happen.  There's no need to write your own 64 bit math libraries on any modern compiler.

Comment: Division is not part of the library, but the language.

Comment: @Olaf  yes, it's part of the language.  It is, however, implemented in many cases as a function automatically provided by the tool chain because the part doesn't support it with an instruction. Why you downvote this is mindboggling.  If this answer is incorrect in fact, please provide your own that is more factually correct.

Comment: libc and compiler are often two different things. Embedded systems are typically _freestanding environment_ which don't support the standard library. Yet they have to support the language standard. Which includes operators for all standard integer types. If the platform does not support them natively, either a compiler-library (e.g. libgcc) or other run-time provides helper functions. But they are not meant to be called from the application code **as functions** as they often don't use the regular ABI.

Comment: @Olaf thank you for restating the same thing I did that you downvoted.

Comment: @RussSchultz: It it was the same thing, why did you feel you have to edit? I'm fine with the change now. It might look nit-pick from your point, but I met a lot of "embedded programmers" who exactly had the same problem as OP just because they had no standard library and thought this was required to support operations not directly supported by the CPU. YMMV, but I think my experience made the DV necessary and hope you'll edit (late comments are rarely read).

Comment: @RussSchultz : Yes we are in violent agreement! ;-)

Comment: Gentleman, 
I found the mistake. It is not in this C++ code, but in C code I did not post (I cannot). I am following a very complex/boring guideline. Regarding the mistake, was something like variable names. 
That one is correct! I am sorry for the waste of time.

Answer (score -1):

There's apparently an equivalent function [in the Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v2.6.22/lib/div64.c) (deliberately linked to an older revision; newer ones seem more complex).

Perhaps you could use that as inspiration? (And please do not copy-paste, unless you're willing to license your code under the GPL too.)

Comment: No problem, this is a generic code.
Thank you for your attention @AKX. Do you know any other sources related to Unions/Structs?

Comment: Gentleman, I found the mistake. It is not in this C++ code, but in C code I did not post (I cannot). I am following a very complex/boring guideline. Regarding the mistake, was something like variable names. 
That one is correct! I am sorry for the waste of time.